# CameraX PreviewView in RelativeLayout goes beyond the bounds

Tags: android-studio, android-layout, android-camerax

I have an XML file that is a RelativeLayout with two children: a PreviewView and a LinearLayout like so:

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

        <androidx.camera.view.PreviewView
            android:id="@+id/preview_view"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:padding="10px"/>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@drawable/border"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </LinearLayout>

    </RelativeLayout>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

border.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:shape="rectangle">
    <stroke android:width="5dip" android:color="@android:color/white" />
</shape>
```

The LinearLayout is intended to overlay the PreviewView and show a border. But the PreviewView seems to go beyond the size LinearLayout even though both have the match_parent constraint. How do I constrain it to actually match_parent?

These are dependencies i am using:

```
// Barcode model dependencies
implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:16.1.0'

// CameraX dependencies
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.0.0-rc01"
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha20"
```

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce it. Could you share the code to your entire layout? And what version of camera-view are you using?

Comment: I updated the post to include the code to the entire layout.

Comment: Still not able to reproduce your issue. The preview is not displayed beyond the bounds of the LinearLayout, it's displayed at the center of the screen inside the box (border). Could you share a screenshot of what you're seeing?